# Running exported Unity project in UnityPlayer initialized in Android Studio

Tags: google-project-tango

Is it possible to run a Unity project, which uses TangoSDK, in the UnityPlayer created in an Android Studio project? Or is building and running a Unity Tango project directly from Unity the only option to create Unity projects for Android that use TangoSDK?

This is what I am doing step by step:

> 1. I have a basic Tango scene created in Unity.
> 2. I export it as Google Android Project in the Build Settings
> 3. I have a simple Android Studio project in which I initialize a UnityPlayer in the onCreate() method of the main activity.
> 4. I copy over the /assets and /libs folder from the exported Unity project to the Android Studio project. This copies all the necessary libraries and assets. I merge the AndroidManifest files so that they contain all the necessary permissions and point to the appropriate main activity.
> 5. When I build this project from Android Studio the Unity Player never launches (never goes past the Unity Logo screen).

I have tried the above steps with a simple Unity Projects that doesn't use TangoSDK and it worked just fine. I tried debugging the app and it appears that the problem is in the TangoService_connect() method that is being called from the library_tango_api library.

Has anyone tried this method of creating a Unity Tango app for Android before? I need to use a lot of Android API methods so I would like to make use of them on the Android's java side and then communicate with Unity via UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(). Or is using AndroidJavaObjects in Unity my only option?

Comment: I experimented a bit more and the issue is that I am trying to get access to the camera on the Android side with Camera.open(2); so Tango Service can't get access to the locked camera. The question I have now is that camera 2 is a back facing camera, which I thought was not used by Tango Service. Can someone verify this? Does Tango Service want to consume all three cameras (front-facing, wide angle and back-facing)? If yes, what does it need the back-facing one for?

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using?

If you are only using motion tracking or area learning in, you should have access to the RGBIR camera. If you are using depth perception the Tango API will consume the rear-facing RGBIR camera.

Comment: @ChaseCobb I am on the latest build and the most recent SDK and I am not using the depth provider (set enableDepth to false). I now tried to access the rear-facing camera from Unity. I project it onto a WebCamTexture after Tango is initialized. The front-facing camera works fine but the rear-facing camera gives the same error " **An error occurred while connecting to camera: 2
E/Unity﹕ Unable to initialize camera: Fail to connect to camera service**". If I run webcamtexture.Play() with access to camera 2 before Tango is initialized, then Tango fails to initialize and breaks.

Comment: Also, make sure the TangoConfig isn't being initialized by default to enable the camera, or depth.

Comment: @ChaseCobb I am using the 'Unity Motion Tracking' scene from the examples. TangoConfig is set to TANGO_CONFIG_DEFAULT (I also tried setting it to TANGO_CONFIG_MOTION_TRACKING), m_enableDepth is set to false, same result...

Answer (score 0):

Anton, Fisheye camera and front face camera are consuming a same channel on the hardware level, so you won't be able to use both of them. However, you will be able to use the depth/backfacing camera and front camera together..

Comment: I understand this, I am only trying to use front-facing and rear-facing together, not fisheye.